# Content-Disposition downloading wrong file

Tags: php, html, internet-explorer-11, content-disposition

I am trying to download a file. I am using IE11. I have tried several methods to do this. Currently I am trying to use the header with Content-Disposition method. I have tried to do this a few different ways according to other answers people have given. And it does download. But instead of downloading the file I point it to, it downloads the file it is written in. So if I tell it to download example.txt in my test.php file. It will only download test.php.

These are the methods I have tried:

This one is written in test.html:

```
<?php
$filename = "example.txt"
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($filename) . '"');
?>
```

I've also tried making it a button:

```
<a href="download.php?file=example.txt">BUTTON</a>
```

Where download.php is:

```
<?php
$file = $_GET['file'];  
header('Content-type: audio/mpeg');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file.'"');
?>
```

I tried this:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/download');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="example.txt"');
header("Content-Length: " . filesize("example.txt"));

$fp = fopen("example.txt", "r");
fpassthru($fp);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

And this:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($File) . "\"");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($File));
header("Connection: close");
```

There are many more slight variations and mix and matching that I have tried. All have the same problem that the .html or .php file downloads rather than example.txt. Does anyone know why this would happen? Is something not supported in IE11? I do not think it is a syntax error simply because most of these I copied from other answers online. I have tried with example.txt existing and not existing, in this folder and other folders.

EDIT: So it turns out that these all work, I was just using them wrong. I had been trying to make isolated files to run this code so I could test it without interference from the rest of the functions on my website, but this left the php files without the resources they needed to actually run properly. When I put the code into the actual files on the website it worked perfectly. smh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
 header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
 header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
 header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($File));
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($File));
 readfile($File);
 exit;
```

Comment: Don't set `Content-Type` to something it isn't

Comment: This is close. It seems to be looking at example.txt. But now it opens the contents of example.txt in a new tab, rather than giving the download prompt.

Comment: Replace  header("Content-Type: application/force-download"); by   header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');

Comment: Actually it's not doing anything now. I realized it was only opening example.txt in another tab because I had made a link to it. I try putting the suggested code in test.html and in download.php.

Comment: If you see my edit, you'll see that it turns out my problem was with where my files were. Your answer does work though so I'm going to count it. Thank you for trying to help. :)